# how to make a column's value match all the values from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How to get the column's values which match all the values from a subquery?

Here my table :

```
Table P
p# - pname - color - city
1  -  nut  -  Red  - London
2  -  Bolt - Green - Paris
3  - Screw - Blue  - Rome
4  - Cam   - Blue  - Paris
...
```

For example, if I want the name of the cities which have the same color of piece (P)?

I was thinking about this query:

```
SELECT city
FROM P
WHERE city = 'blue';
```

Of course, it's cheating because I only have a few rows, so how do you write a query that can generalize it ?

*Maybe using EXISTS or NOT EXISTS ?

Comment: Can you provide sample data *and* desired output?  Also, your question uses the word "hide", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: And it doesn't make sense to say city = 'blue' but I'm not sure if that's not attributable to confusion about what a `where` clauses does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the name of cities where the colors are the same as a given city.  If so, you can use a join and aggregation:

```
select p.city
from P p join
     P p1
     on p1.city = 'Rome' and
        p1.city <> p.city and
        p1.color = p.color
group by p.city
having count(distinct color) = (select count(distinct color) from p where city = 'Rome');
```